# Why rename a surah of 'Abu Lahab '

Tags: quran, surah

A Few days ago I have known surah `Abu lahab` rename as `Al-Masad`. I don't know why do change the surah name. If any one know that, explain me please.

Comment: I have found three names: al-Lahab, al-Masad and tabat. The surah was never called surat abu Lahab. Do you have any source for your claim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Surahs* can have multiple names. What names is used by a certain person or in a certain publication would depend on convention: the name that they perceive is more familiar to their audience.

[Chapter 111](https://quran.com/111) is called تبت (Tabat) from the first word of the first verse, لهب (Lahab) from the fourth word of the first verse and مسد (Masad) from the last word of the last verse.

Some other examples:

- [Chapter 9](https://quran.com/9) is called براءة (Baraat) from the first word of the first verse or التوبة (Tawbah) from the the seventh word of the  [104](https://quran.com/9/104)'th verse.
- [Chapter 17](https://quran.com/17) is called  الإسراء (Isra) from the 3rd word of the first verse and بني اسراييل (Bani Israel) from the 6th and 7th words of the second verse.
- [Chapter 41](https://quran.com/41) is called حم السجدۃ (Ha-Meem Al Sajdah) from the disjoint letters of the first verse and  فصلت (Fussilat) from the second word of the third verse.
- [Chapter 47](https://quran.com/47) is called  محمد (Muhammad) from the ninth word of the second verse and القتال (Qital) from the 13th word of the [20](https://quran.com/47/20)th verse.
- [Chapter 76](https://quran.com/76) is called الانسان(Al-Insaan) and  الدهر (Ad-Dahr) from the 4th and 7th words of the first verse.