# Why does surah nr. 40 have two different names?

Tags: quran, names, surah

I've read different names of surah nr. 40 in two qurans. The one was surah ghafir (the forgiver) and the other one was surah mu'min (the believer).
So my further questions are:
Who gave the names of all the surah?
I mean the quran in the book form was made after the prophet (peace be upon him) died. Did he gave the instruction to the order and name of all the surah?
And why does some surah have multiple names?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I strongly recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help]. Your question seem to have been asked and answered before: [Who named the chapters of the quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10923/who-named-the-chapters-of-the-quran) also relevant [Why rename a surah of abu Lahab?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/44594/why-rename-a-surah-of-abu-lahab?)

Answer (score 1):

Allah has many names like Allah, Ar-Rahman, Ar-Raheem, Al-Malik, Al-Qudoos ...

Muhammad (SAW) has many names like Muhammad, Ahmed, Al-Muzzammil, Al-Muddathir, Rasul Allah ...

Quran has many names like Quran, Furqan, Al-Kitab, Al-Hakim ...

Similarly many Surahs have multiple names.

The order of the Surahs are from wahi, as Jibreel used to go through the Quran with Muhammad (SAW). The same is the nature of the names of the Surahs. Refer to https://islamqa.info/en/131664